# Change Button Value Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a page with riddles and after every riddle an answer button and onclick shows the answer but also changes the value of the button into hide so when you press again the button you hide the answer. I made something but I'm a beginner in Javascript so I can't figure out what I did wrong:[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hPQP9/118/)

html:

```html
<input type="button" value="Answer" onclick="return change(this);" />
<p id="click">This is the riddle answer.</p>
```

css:

```css
#click{
display:none;}
```

js:

```javascript
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).change(function(){
        if (el.value == "Answer" ){
            $("p#click").removeClass("click");
            el.value = "Hide";
        } else if ( el.value = "Hide";) {
            $("p#click").addClass("click");
        }
    });
});
```

I want to be **something like this**: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEyBa/12/) but 1 single button which can change its value and change from answer to hide and from hide to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **[updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/LEyBa/13/)**

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
      if ($(this).text() == "Show")
       $(this).text("Hide")
    else
       $(this).text("Show");
      $("span").slideToggle();

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for you :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
      $("#click").slideToggle();
      if($("#show").val() == 'Show')    {
        $("#show").val('Hide');
      }else {
        $("#show").val('Show');
      }
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#click{
display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Show" id="show" />
<p id="click">This is the riddle answer.</p>
</body>
</html>
```